# How to rotate object around a pivot point as described in THREE.js solution in vanilla webgl?

Tags: javascript, webgl

I want to make transforms around a pivot point using webgl. Inspired by Three.js and [this comment](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/1364#issuecomment-4057171)

> Create a object that will act as pivot:
>
> mesh.position.y = 10;
>
> var pivot = new THREE.Object3D();
>   pivot.add( mesh );
>
> scene.add( pivot );

I am trying to set the pivot to some point and rotate the object. Here's my code to do these:

```
  let transforms = {};

  this.makeTransform = (name, transform) => {

    transforms[name] = modelMatrix(transform);

  };

  const modelMatrix = transform => {
    let matrix = transforms[transform.transform] || mat4.identity();

    return mat4.transform(matrix, transform);
  };


  const mvpMatrix = modelMatrix => {
    const { pos: camPos, target, up } = camera;
    const { fov, aspect, near, far } = camera;

    let camMatrix = mat4.lookAt(camPos, target, up);
    let viewMatrix = mat4.inverse(camMatrix);

    let projectionMatrix = mat4.perspective(fov, aspect, near, far);

    let viewProjectionMatrix = mat4.multiply(projectionMatrix, viewMatrix);

    return mat4.multiply(viewProjectionMatrix, modelMatrix);
  };



  this.drawMesh = (name, transform) => {    
    const uMatrix = mvpMatrix(modelMatrix(transform));
    // set uMatrix as uniform and draw
  }
```

Usage (render code):

```
r.makeTransform('root', {
  translate: [100, 0, 0]
});

r.drawMesh('sample', {
  transform: 'root',
  translate: [0.0, 0.0, 2.0],
  rotate: [0.0,
           Math.PI,
           0.0]
});
```

So I don't have a scene graph, but I make transform matrices and apply them to objects. Here `sample` mesh is applied a `root` transform. This translates the object on the x axis, and still rotates the object around it's origin.

But I can't rotate the object around a pivot point using the mentioned approach.

Based on gman answer **this works**:

```
r.makeTransform('root', {
  translate: [0, 0, 0],
  rotate: [0.0, u.PI, 0.0]
});

r.drawMesh('sample', {
  transform: 'root',
  translate: [100.0, 0.0, 0.0]
});
```

---

#### How does THREE.js rotate around the center of the object by default?

Because the vertices in geometries are defined so that the object center is at 0,0 origin.

like [here](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/src/geometries/BoxGeometry.js#L123)

```
 var x = ix * segmentWidth - widthHalf;
```

or [here](https://github.com/eguneys/fhree-examples/blob/master/src/geometry/box.js#L22)

```
  for (let i = 0; i < vertices.length; i+=3) {
    vertices[i] -= widthHalf;
    vertices[i+1] -= heightHalf;
    vertices[i+2] -= depthHalf;
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A scene graph is just a way to represent a hierarchy of matrices. Here's a simple human scene graph

```
root
 └─base
    └─waist
       ├─chest
       │  ├─neck
       │  │  └─head
       │  ├─left arm
       │  │  └─left forearm
       │  │     └─left hand
       │  └─right arm
       │     └─right forearm
       │        └─right hand
       ├─left thigh
       │  └─left leg
       │     └─left foot
       └─right thigh
          └─right left
             └─right foot
```

So to draw the right arm based on stereotypical webgl matrix math its

```
projectionMatrix * viewMatrix * rootMatrix * baseMatrix
   * waistMatrix * chestMatrix * rightArmMatrix * rightForeArmMatrix
   * rightHandMatrix
```

So looking at that you can translate any three.js scenegraph into plain matrix math. If it's

```
scene.add(pivot);
pivot.add(mesh);
```

Then your scene graph looks like

```
scene
 └─pivot
    └─mesh
```

so you need to end up with

```
projectionMatrix * viewMatrix * sceneMatrix * pivotMatrix * meshMatrix
```

Or to look at it another way

```
modelMatrix = sceneMatrix * pivotMatrix * meshMatrix

projectMatrix * viewMatrix * modelMatrix
```

The scenegraph itself just a way to make it easy it organize the matrices in a generic and flexible way rather than hard code all the math.

Note: sceneMatrix is usually the identity so you can leave it out but technically the scene in three.js is another node in the scene graph and so itself represents a matrix.